# Url doubles for post pages with categories

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I'm getting url doubles for post page for all categories.

For example:
https://www.lawfirmuk.net/post/immigration-health-surcharge-rise-come-effect-no-earlier-16-january-2024
https://www.lawfirmuk.net/post_e/immigration-health-surcharge-rise-come-effect-no-earlier-16-january-2024
https://www.lawfirmuk.net/post_cn/immigration-health-surcharge-rise-come-effect-no-earlier-16-january-2024
https://www.lawfirmuk.net/post_uk/immigration-health-surcharge-rise-come-effect-no-earlier-16-january-2024

I've checked this article and it has chosen category: https://prnt.sc/Jei66bVKJGoU

So I want the post to have a url only for the chosen category. So for this post it would be:
https://www.lawfirmuk.net/post_e/immigration-health-surcharge-rise-come-effect-no-earlier-16-january-2024

Is there any way to fix this issue?

I wrote to the Rainlab Blog creator and he advised me to look for help elsewhere.